# Ref value always undefined in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined, ref

I don't understand why my ref's value is always undefined. I know this kind of question has already been posted but nothing helps.

Here is my code :

```
class CallsHandler extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleRegistration = this.handleRegistration.bind(this);
        this.usernameInput = React.createRef();
    }
    handleRegistration() {
        console.log(this.usernameInput.current.value);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Username</Text>
                <TextInput ref={this.usernameInput}></TextInput>
                <Button title="REGISTER" onPress={this.handleRegistration}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your method to component context

onPress={this.handleRegistration.bind(this)}

Comment: Thank you but it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <TextInput ref={input => (this.nameInput = input)}></TextInput>
```

Also remove this line `this.usernameInput = React.createRef();`